# Jersey memory leak?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, jersey, dropwizard

I have the following code snippet.  Simple service that returns an image when the endpoint is called.

```
@GET
@Path("/categories/{category}/image")
@Produces("image/jpeg")
@UnitOfWork
public StreamingOutput getCategoryImage(@PathParam("category")Category category){

//foo service will return an Optional

    return fooService.getImage(category).map(new Function<InputStream, StreamingOutput>() {
        @Override
        public StreamingOutput apply(InputStream inputStream) {
            return (StreamingOutput) output -> BarResource.this.copyAndClose(inputStream, output);
        }
    })
            .orElseThrow(NotFoundException::new);
}


//Originally this method did not exist, but I am trying this to close the 'leak'

private long copyAndClose(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException{
    try(InputStream temp = inputStream; OutputStream tempOut = outputStream) {
        return IOUtils.copy(temp, tempOut);
    }
}
```

However through a stress test, we called this 1600 times / sec for a few seconds and the memory usage in our docker container sky rocketed (from about about 300 to over a gig) we have set the Xmx to 512 but the memory keeps on climbing.

Am I missing something here?  We are using Dropwizard and Jersey.

Answer (score 0):

After running a profiler I found that we were creating several thousand objects in response to this call in the FooService.  We were able to make it a singleton and that seems to have addressed a lot of the concerns.